# what is the difference between int(input()) and just input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, syntax, integer

I am new to python, and when I use the input() for any inputs including numbers it works, but my teacher is saying to use int(input()) for integer-based inputs. Can someone explain what is the difference between these syntaxes?

Comment: Converts the input to integer. By default, inputs in Python are in string form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One of them has `int` around it, and the other doesn't. Consequently, where `int` is present, it does the thing that it normally does. To understand it properly, you should try reading documentation and/or following a tutorial. More to the point: if your teacher says something that you do not understand, you should **ask your teacher** for clarification. If someone tells you to do something and you do not understand why, the "why?" question is best directed at that person.

Comment: It's good that you are asking this question but did you first ask your teacher about this? What did they say?

Comment: I did ask them but they just repeated the statement, I didn't want to keep nagging them so I kept this question in the back of my mind. I am not saying they don't know the answer but I think they just didn't care? I guess?.

Comment: @dash I understand. But you can always try to ask for some more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a `string`.

To change it to a number(an `integer`) do `int()`, so it would be `int(input())`.

Comment: To expand on this: `"1" != 1`